Why is `null` interpreted as `any` in function generic?
I joined a new project and suddenly when I copy over my old snippets, they don't work the way they used to.
Why is the null interpreted as any in the function generic?
In its simplest form, this is the issue, where null results in any generic.
function useToggle<Initial>(initialState: Initial) { }

useToggle(true)  // useToggled<boolean>(initialState: boolean): void
useToggle(false) // useToggled<boolean>(initialState: boolean): void
useToggle(null)  // useToggled<any>(initialState: any): void

This is ultimately the form that I need.
Basically, when the useToggle(null) is initialized with null, it will return null as its first value, afterwards it will toggle between true | false, however, I am unable to type the return type with boolean | null, which results in unsafe code.
function useToggle<Initial extends boolean | null, R = Initial extends null ? boolean | null : boolean>(initialState: Initial): R { return }

useToggle(true)  // useToggler<true, boolean>(initialState: true): boolean
useToggle(false) // useToggler<false, boolean>(initialState: false): boolean
useToggle(null)  // useToggler<any, boolean>(initialState: any): boolean  <-  wrong (unexpected)

What I expect and need is this:
useToggle(null)  // useToggle<null, boolean | null>(initialState: null): boolean | null

How can I achieve this?

Upon further testing and after I created a TS playground, despite both, the playground and my env using same version 5.7.2, I realized that this must be local config issue.
TS playground link
What I needed to do is enable strictNullChecks in tsconfig.json.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
}

